# Merging D3 Scatterplot with D3 Google Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, d3.js, scatter-plot

I have implement a D3, Google map and plotted the Latitude and Longitude points from a .csv file onto the Google map. The following is the D3 code that builds the map and plots the data points from the .csv file.

```
// Create the Google Map…
var map = new google.maps.Map(d3.select("#map").node(), {
  zoom: 7,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.5000, 0.1167),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var data = [
      { oa: "E00000001", lng: -0.095154937, lat: 51.520236 },
      { oa: "E00000003", lng: -0.096352226, lat: 51.519869 },  
      { oa: "E00000005", lng: -0.096674785, lat: 51.519047 },
      { oa: "E00000007", lng: -0.096970467, lat: 51.516795 },
      { oa: "E00000010", lng: -0.097464624, lat: 51.522576 },
      { oa: "E00000012", lng: -0.09591956 , lat: 51.521948 },
      { oa: "E00000013", lng: -0.096452804, lat: 51.520914 },
      { oa: "E00000014", lng: -0.096907519, lat: 51.522108 },
      { oa: "E00000016", lng: -0.093145103, lat: 51.521076 },
      { oa:"E00000017", lng: -0.091830999, lat: 51.520443 },
    ];


// Load the station data. When the data comes back, create an overlay.
var overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();

// Add the container when the overlay is added to the map.
overlay.onAdd = function() {
  var layer = d3.select(this.getPanes().overlayLayer).append("div")
        .attr("height", "100%")
        .attr("width", "100%")
        .attr("class", "stations")
        .attr("id", "layer");

  layer[0][0].style.width = "1366px";
  layer[0][0].parentNode.style.width = "100%";
  layer[0][0].parentNode.style.height = "100%";
  layer[0][0].parentNode.parentNode.style.width = "100%";
  layer[0][0].parentNode.parentNode.style.height = "100%";
  layer[0][0].parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.width = "100%";
  layer[0][0].parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.height = "100%";
  layer[0][0].parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.width = "100%";
  layer[0][0].parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.height = "100%";

  // Draw each marker as a separate SVG element.
  // We could use a single SVG, but what size would it have?
  overlay.draw = function() {
    var projection = this.getProjection(),
        padding = 10;

    var marker = layer.selectAll("svg")
        .data( data )
        .each(transform) // update existing markers
      .enter().append("svg:svg")
        .each(transform)
        .attr("class", "marker aaa")

    marker.append("svg:circle")
        .attr("r", 7)
        .attr("cx", padding )
        .attr("cy", padding );

    // add a label.
    marker.append("svg:text")
        .attr("x", padding + 7)
        .attr("y", padding)
        .attr("dy", ".31em")
        .text( function(d) { 
          return d.oa; }
        );

    var v = d3.geom.voronoi( translate(data) );
    console.log( "v is :" );
    console.log( v );

    var edges = layer.selectAll("path")
        .data( v )
      .enter().append("svg:svg").attr("width", "100%").attr("width","100%").style("position", "absolute")
        .append("svg:path")
        .attr( "d", function(d){
          var e = transform_path(d)
          var p = 'M' + e.join('L') + 'Z'
          console.log( 'PATH: ' + p)
          return p
        }).attr("fill", "none").attr("stroke", "black")
        ;

    function translate(data) {
      var d = []
      for( var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
        var c = [ data[i].lat, data[i].lng ]
        d.push( c )
      }
      return d
    }

    function _projection( lat, lng ) {
      e = new google.maps.LatLng( lat, lng );
      e = projection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(e);
      return [ e.x - padding, e.y - padding]
      // return [ e.x, e.y ]
    }

    function transform(d) {
      e = _projection( d.lat, d.lng )
      console.log("marker " + d.lat +', ' + d.lng + " -> left: " + e[0] +", top: " + e[1] )
      return d3.select(this)
          .style("left", e[0] + "px")
          .style("top", e[1] + "px");
    }

    function transform_path(data) {
      var d = []
      console.log(data)
      for( var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
        var c = _projection( data[i][0], data[i][1] )
        console.log( ' path point: ' + JSON.stringify(data[i]) + ' -> left: ' + c[0] + ", top: " + c[1])
        d.push( c )
      }
      // console.log(d)
      return d
    }

  };
};

// Bind our overlay to the map…
overlay.setMap(map);
```

Now using the same map D3 code I want to alter it to allow me to use the D3 Scatterplot Matrix Brushing [Scatterplot](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063663) on the map.

More precisely I am trying to get the same brush selection (from the Scatterplot example) with the map and my plotted data points.

I have tried playing around with the Scatterplot and the D3 Google map code to merge them some how but cannot seen to get the brush selection form the Scatterplot example to work on my map.

here is the Scatterplot code:

```
<b>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

svg {
   font: 10px sans-serif;
   padding: 10px;
}

.axis,
.frame {
   shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.axis line {
   stroke: #ddd;
}

.axis path {
   display: none;
}

.frame {
   fill: none;
   stroke: #aaa;
}

circle {
   fill-opacity: .7;
}

circle.hidden {
   fill: #ccc !important;
}

.extent {
   fill: #000;
   fill-opacity: .125;
   stroke: #fff;
 }

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 960,
  size = 150,
  padding = 19.5;

var x = d3.scale.linear()
  .range([padding / 2, size - padding / 2]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .range([size - padding / 2, padding / 2]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .orient("bottom")
  .ticks(5);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient("left")
  .ticks(5);

var color = d3.scale.category10();

d3.csv("flowers.csv", function(error, data) {
  var domainByTrait = {},
    traits = d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(d) { return d !== "species"; }),
  n = traits.length;

  traits.forEach(function(trait) {
    domainByTrait[trait] = d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d[trait]; });
```

});

```
  xAxis.tickSize(size * n);
  yAxis.tickSize(-size * n);

  var brush = d3.svg.brush()
   .x(x)
   .y(y)
   .on("brushstart", brushstart)
   .on("brush", brushmove)
   .on("brushend", brushend);

  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
   .attr("width", size * n + padding)
   .attr("height", size * n + padding)
  .append("g")
   .attr("transform", "translate(" + padding + "," + padding / 2 + ")");

  svg.selectAll(".x.axis")
   .data(traits)
  .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(" + (n - i - 1) *  size + ",0)"; })
   .each(function(d) { x.domain(domainByTrait[d]);    d3.select(this).call(xAxis); });

  svg.selectAll(".y.axis")
   .data(traits)
  .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * size + ")"; })
   .each(function(d) { y.domain(domainByTrait[d]);  d3.select(this).call(yAxis); });

  var cell = svg.selectAll(".cell")
   .data(cross(traits, traits))
  .enter().append("g")
   .attr("class", "cell")
   .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + (n - d.i - 1) * size + "," + d.j * size + ")"; })
   .each(plot);

 // Titles for the diagonal.
 cell.filter(function(d) { return d.i === d.j; }).append("text")
   .attr("x", padding)
   .attr("y", padding)
   .attr("dy", ".71em")
   .text(function(d) { return d.x; });

 cell.call(brush);

function plot(p) {
  var cell = d3.select(this);

  x.domain(domainByTrait[p.x]);
  y.domain(domainByTrait[p.y]);

  cell.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "frame")
    .attr("x", padding / 2)
    .attr("y", padding / 2)
    .attr("width", size - padding)
    .attr("height", size - padding);

  cell.selectAll("circle")
    .data(data)
   .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d[p.x]); })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d[p.y]); })
    .attr("r", 3)
    .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.species); });
 }

 var brushCell;

// Clear the previously-active brush, if any.
function brushstart(p) {
if (brushCell !== this) {
  d3.select(brushCell).call(brush.clear());
  x.domain(domainByTrait[p.x]);
  y.domain(domainByTrait[p.y]);
  brushCell = this;
}
}

// Highlight the selected circles.
function brushmove(p) {
var e = brush.extent();
svg.selectAll("circle").classed("hidden", function(d) {
  return e[0][0] > d[p.x] || d[p.x] > e[1][0]
      || e[0][1] > d[p.y] || d[p.y] > e[1][1];
});
}

// If the brush is empty, select all circles.
function brushend() {
if (brush.empty()) svg.selectAll(".hidden").classed("hidden", false);
}

function cross(a, b) {
var c = [], n = a.length, m = b.length, i, j;
for (i = -1; ++i < n;) for (j = -1; ++j < m;) c.push({x: a[i], i: i, y: b[j], j: j});
return c;
```

}

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", size * n + padding + 20 + "px");
});

```
</script>
</b>
```

Can any one help me with this?